# Use revalue in data manipulation with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I wanted to use the following code, but its not working and I have no idea why?:

```
data <- data.frame(variable1 = as.factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), each=5)),
                   variable2 = rnorm(15,10,2))

require(plyr)
require(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
 revalue(variable1, c("A"="House", "B"="Flat", "C"="Loft"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `variable1` is not a factor or character vector.  It's the "name" of a column in a data frame.  The `revalue` function expects factors or character vectors.  You can eliminate the problem by using the `mutate()` function like this:

```
# your code    
data <- data.frame(variable1 = as.factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), each=5)),
                   variable2 = rnorm(15,10,2))

require(plyr)
require(dplyr)

# corrected code
data <- 
    data %>%
        mutate(variable1 = revalue(variable1, c("A"="House", "B"="Flat", "C"="Loft")))
```

Comment: I want to mention here, that it is important to load plyr before dplyr.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I read elsewhere, that there is a possibility to do the same thing without the plyr package, by using recode(), however recode seems to be a function from the car package.